# How do I select distinct from the Django model

Tags: django, django-models

If only address and address_detail variables are the same among model variables, I want to remove duplicates. 
How should I use select distinct address, address_detail?

```
class Information(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address_detail = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

(table) 
user, my address, my address detail, 11122, myemail@email.com 
user, my address, my address detail, 12345, test@email.com 
user, my address, my address detail, 22211, example@email.com

(result) 
user, my address, my address detail, 11122, myemail@email.com

Comment: `Information.objects.distinct('address', 'address_detail')`. But looking at your result, which `user` and which `zip code` and which `email` should be returned? Just the first one? With the `distinct()` clause you can't be sure which one you get, it'll probably be the last one inserted in the db.

Comment: user will use filter..`Information.objects.filter(user=user)` and The zip code and the email will bring the first one.

Comment: adding to @dirkgroten comment, [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) with arguments works with postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`distinct(*fields)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) in your *QuerySet*. Note this works only with PostgreSQL.

Alternatively, if you're not on PostgreSQL, you can do this:

```
from django.db.models import Max

distinct_by_address = Information.objects.values('address', 'address_detail')\
    .annotate(last_pk=Max('pk'))\
    .values('last_pk')
result = Information.objects.filter(pk__in=distinct_by_address)
```

This groups by address and address_detail (so will only take one for each duplicate combination) and picks the last (highest) pk. Then we just filter the objects on this pk so that we can show the other fields.

However this is less flexible because you have to aggregate on 'pk' or another **unique** field that can be ordered and works with `Max` or `Min`.

Comment: Is there any other way to use it in MySQL?

Comment: Your answer solved my problem perfectly. Thank you!!